# AVD Manager - No system image installed for this target

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to create Android Virtual Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488419/unable-to-create-android-virtual-device)

The CPU/ABI field in Android New AVD popup window shows "No system image installed for this target".

How do I fix this?

Comment: download it with your sdk manager ( ARM , X86 )

Comment: refer this wonderful answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13488547/603233

Answer (score 23):

Open your Android SDK Manager and ensure that you download/install a system image for the API level you are developing with.

Answer (score 4):

you should android sdk manager install 4.2 apı 17 -> ARM EABI v7a System Image

if not installed ARM EABI v7a System Image, you should install all.

Comment: After install you should  restart eclipse