# Creating a new AVD- CPU/ABI field show 'No System images installed'

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device

I was onto creating a new AVD. I created one with the ARM CPU image. But it won't boot up even after about 45 minutes. So I deleted it and downloaded the Intel x86 Atom image. On creating the AVD the field to select the CPU became inactive and shows 'No System Images installed for this  target.
Help.!
Image installation status in SDK Manager:

[image: Image installation status in SDK Manager]

[image]

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it helped? The answers bellow solved the issue I hope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It worked after a simple restart of the Eclipse.

Answer (score 14):

Make sure that system image is installed. The system image for that platform is not installed. Go to SDK Manager and tick them and install. Then, try to 
create new AVD.

Answer (score 8):

What I have done is:

1. I'll Android SDK Manager. I have installed the following points;
   Platform SDK.
   ARM EABI V7A System Image

For the API you need.

close eclipse

1. After I go to Windows Explorer. A folder:
   ..\sdk\system-images
   And entered into the System image that you use, I can inside a folder called "default" and in "armeabi-v7a" only have to cut and move the last folder where the default and then delete default.

open eclipse

This works.

Answer (score 3):

You must install the system image for your SDK version.
for more information please check this answer.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488419/unable-to-create-android-virtual-device)