# Starting app on android emulator for meteor never finishes

Tags: android, meteor, android-emulator

Today I wanted to test how Meteor's android build worked. So I installed Meteor and created a test to-do app per [their instructions](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app). Then pr. instructions [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441441/meteor-js-on-windows-support-for-ios-and-android) I installed the Java SDK, and confirmed I had the Android SDK from when I installed Visual Studio 2015.

Then came my first problem. When I tried to run `meteor add-platform android` from the command prompt. I got the error *Cannot find module ‘is-property’*, and quickly learned to fix this by cd'ing to the directory missing the module and running `npm install is-property`. [A hat tip to this thread for the solution](https://forums.meteor.com/t/cannot-find-module-is-property/26029).

Okay, one more time: `meteor add-platform android` and this time with success. I then ran `meteor run android`, and sure enough, an emulator launched with my app. Or almost. Because the first message that greeted me was *Application Error - The connection to the server was unsuccessful (http://localhost:12784)* and the app crashed.

After searching around a bit, it seemed that because the emulator was so damn slow, the meteor script timed out and caused the crash. So I then tried installing [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) to use [Android AVD manager](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html). But now the emulator wouldn't even launch, and I got stock with the following:

[image]

*Starting app on android emulator* and then... nothing.

So I tried to uninstall all android sdks, android studio, and meteor.

Then I tried to

1. Installing meteor again.
2. Install only the [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads) command line tools.
3. [Added the Android SDK to my environment variables](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#installing-prerequisites-android).
4. Ran the android.bat to make sure I installed almost all the newest tools and images plus the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)
   [image: List item]
5. I Then tried running the `meteor run android` command again, only to get stuck at *starting app on android emulator* as seen in the first picture.
6. Let the *Starting app on android emulator* run for an hour plus to see if things were just slow.

I have also tried to follow advice from the following resources without help:

- [Android Emulator Hangs](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5612)
- [Meteor with android having issue starting app on the device and emulator](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5531)
- [Creating a new AVD- CPU/ABI field show 'No System images installed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216256/creating-a-new-avd-cpu-abi-field-show-no-system-images-installed)
- [Unable to create Android Virtual Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488419/unable-to-create-android-virtual-device)

And btw, here is how my AVD config looks like

[image]

So what have I done wrong? *Everything* would not be a surprising answer. Jokes aside, ***what is it I need to do to get a proper running android emulator up for my meteor app on windows 10?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting exactly the same thing, but I finally figured out the problem.

I tried running the emulator from the command-line:

```
emulator -avd Android_Emulator
```

This actually gave me a useful error message:

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAXM is not installed on this machine
```

This StackOverflow thread helped figure out how to install this:  [Intel X86 emulator accelerator (HAXM installer) VT/NX not enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521014/intel-x86-emulator-accelerator-haxm-installer-vt-nx-not-enabled)

And then it worked!  Really really slow!  But it worked.

Comment: this gave me an error about missing Qt library, which in result led me to missing emulator executable in PATH and this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/44822312/266561

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your Virtual Device and recreate it again, or try a different one. Next, rebuild your meteor app proyect.

Removing you virtual device

**Android-Studio >> Configure >> AVD Manager >> Delete**

In my case, no issues about Intel HXAM (already installed), but the virtual device was working time ago, suddenly, the "Starting app on android emulator" never ended. I think, its about cordova+npm related issues. So, try this.

In meteor proyect folder, try rebuild de app-cordova things using

- Deleting **.meteor/local/corova-build**
- Deleting **.meteor/node_modules**
- Removing and adding android plaftorm with **meteor remove-plarform android && meteor add-platform android**
- Running the commands **meteor rebuild && meteor npm install**
- Ensure compatibility NodeJS libraries. In my case, **meteor 1.8.2, nodejs 12.9**.