# Fail to create Android virtual Device, "No system image installed for this Target"

Tags: wear-os

[Unable to create Android Virtual Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488419/unable-to-create-android-virtual-device/13488547#13488547)
i follwed this link.

I installed all ARM images for each Android more than 4.0.

I installed intel & MIPs as well.

But, still my AVD Manager is saying "NO System images installed for this target".

why, so?

Comment: In SDK manager, do you see Android Wear ARM EAB system image, and is that installed?

Comment: Yea I have installed them

Comment: Are you sure you don't have two different installations of SDK? Can you do the following from command line: (a) go to your SDK root directory (b) change directory to "tools" directory (c) run ./android sdk, then make sure that SDK platform  (API level 19) and Wearable image (Android Wear ARM EAB...), along other required ones mentioned in the documentation are all installed, (d) run "./android avd" and see if it works now or not. In AVD manager, make sure target is set to API level 19, then see if under CPU/ABI you can find the wearable option.

Comment: Also make sure to restart eclipse if you just downloaded them

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In order to create an Android Wear emulator you need to follow the instructions below:

1. If your version of Android SDK Tools is lower than 22.6, you must update
2. Under Android 4.4.2, select Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image and install it.
3. Under Extras, ensure that you have the latest version of the Android Support Library. If an update is available, select Android Support Library. If you're using Android Studio, also select Android Support Repository.

Below is the snapshot of what it should look like:

[image: Screenshot1]

Then you must check the following in order to create a Wearable AVD:

1. For the Device, select Android Wear Square or Android Wear Round.
2. For the Target, select Android 4.4.2 - API Level 19 (or higher, otherwise corresponding system image will not show up.).
3. For the CPU/ABI, select Android Wear ARM (armeabi-v7a).
4. For the Skin, select AndroidWearSquare or AndroidWearRound.
5. Leave all other options set to their defaults and click OK.

[image: Screenshot2]

Then you are good to go. For more information you can always refer to the [developer site](http://developer.android.com/wear/preview/start.html).

Comment: "Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 19" may be easier to locate in the Target drop down... That is not the correct one which was where I ran into problems when trying to create an AVD. The one mentioned in this answer is located higher up in the selection list and may be harder to find right away. So just be careful, there are multiple options with API Level 19 and only the one mentioned above is the correct one.

Comment: Is there any reason for NOT installing all these components? Can it make the virtual device slower? Or can I just check all boxes and space used is the only drawback ?

Comment: @adrianTNT: Which components you asking ?

Comment: I meant the ones with check boxes shown in above image, but since then I found that checking all these components can use around 15GB of space, compared to around 500MB default space used by Android Studio install. So that kind of answered my question.

Answer (score 16):

As a workaround, go to sdk installation directory and perform the following steps:

- Navigate to `system-images/android-19/default`
- Move everything in there to `system-images/android-19/`

The directory structure should look like this:
[image]

And it should work!

Comment: In system-images I have android-22, 23 and 24, but avd manager shows only API 23 and no CPU/ABI for it (eventho I tried moving files from 23's default folder to the parent folder). Any hints what to do? In Android Studios SDK Manager I have everything installed, and it finds everything, but I'm trying to use AVD for nativescript, so I need 'android avd' from terminal to find working avd.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Android Studio .Open the SDK-Manager, checked "Show Package Details"  you will find out "Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image" download it , success !

Answer (score 1):

I had android sdk and android studio installed separately in my system. Android studio had installed its own sdk. After I deleted the stand-alone android sdk, the issue of "“No system image installed for this Target” was gone.