# Unable To Create KitKat AVD with ARM System Image

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to create an AVD for Android `4.4.2 KitKat`. I have the `SDK Platform`, `Google APIs(ARM System Image)` installed. But, whenever I try creating an AVD and select `Target` to `4.4.2`, I get an info like `No system images installed for this target` though I have the `Google APIs(ARM System Image)` installed. Please see the screenshots and help me out.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enable `"Use host GPU"` and check once

Check [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488419/unable-to-create-android-virtual-device/13488547#13488547) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541681/fail-to-create-android-virtual-device-no-system-image-installed-for-this-targe) as well

Comment: Checked `Use host GPU` but it still shows up the same.