# Cant add Virtual Device

Tags: android

Ive started with android development today.
Im having difficulty creating a virtual divice
Ive done everything to the word that the android tutorial said.

But on creating a new device, the target only has one option. `Android4.4W - API Level 20`
This in turn renders the `CPU/ABI` to be greyed out. `No System images installed for this target.`

I went to the `Android SDK Manager` and had to manually add urls to download form.

Here they are:
[image]

My assumption would be that I need a ARM emulator (if you call it that), but I dont know the url to that and also, Im not 100% sure that that is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. Why would this be the case. Installation problems?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23243432/2240163