# AVD no system images installed for this target when editing AVD

Tags: android, edit, android-virtual-device

I have a working AVD. I tried some edits to it.

- When I changed the *Device* from **No device selected** to **Nexus One**, options were available in the *CPU/ABI* dropdown list.
- When I changed it to **Android TV (1080p)**, the *CPU/ABI* dropdown was disabled and its value was changed to **No system images installed for this target**.
- When I changed it back to **Nexus One**, the dropdown remains disabled and its value remained to be **No system images installed for this target**.

Can anybody tell me what is happening here?

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After SDK Update I had the same problems with API Level 19 and 
in my case restarting eclipse solved it.

*In case if it doesn't*

For some reason, in the `sdk/system-images/android-19` directory, sub-folders with system images (armeabi-v7a and x86) were placed within `"default"` directory. 
I just moved them into `android-19` directory (if eclipse is running at the same time, you will have to restart it).

Goto **sdk\system-images** and open the folder of the current API you are using (eg.**android-19** folder in your case).
Now you'll find a folder named **'default'**, open it and you'll see the folder named **'armeabi-v7a'** or which ever system image you've installed.
Now move the folder **'armeabi-v7a'** to the directory **sdk\system-images**...i.e simply out of the **'default'** folder.

[image]

That's it.

Comment: what i did is copy the contents of **default** folder to **\system-images** and when it did not work, I deleted the contents of **default** folder which did not work as well. I don't know what to do. please help. what i want is to create a new avd when higher resolution but "no system images installed for this target" occurs. please help me thanks.

Comment: check this it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541681/fail-to-create-android-virtual-device-no-system-image-installed-for-this-targe

Comment: @mayen I cannot install Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image because its not available. only the two system images are available do you know how to make this available?

Comment: Also, one thing to note in the latest SDK: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210223
So, to create a new AVD with Google APIs support for current SDK, you are supposed to pick generic Android with desired API level as the Target and then pick your desired Google APIs version in CPU/ABI. It works just fine, you will get Google Maps etc. on the AVD.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to emulate an android tv, you must have an appropriate system image for it. Try to look for the corresponding image in your sdk manager. In your case, the system image which you require is **Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image** or **ANDROID TV Intel x86 Atom System Image**. They are available from android 5.0 packages.

Once you have downloaded and installed them, you won't get such a message as **No system images installed for this target**. And then, you will be able to create an AVD for android tv as you wish.

The following image may help you more. Here, the system images are visible under **Android 5.1**. You may also find them under **Android 5.0.1** as I have mentioned earlier.

[image: sdk manager - image]

**Note:** Ensure that the **Updates/New** checkbox is checked in your sdk manager. If it is not checked, you may not get notified about android 5.0 packages if don't have them already in your packages list. Hope you understand what I am saying.

---

**PostScript:** I have no idea about your Nexus One issues. Please add some more details to your question, if anything more you have done. It will be helpful for the answerer.