# System Images for AVD not available only for Android Wear 7.0

Tags: android-studio, wear-os, android-virtual-device

I am not able to create AVD as System images are not available.**I am able to create AVD virtual device for mobile but unable to create  for Android Wear**.

[image]

Comment: I am able to create AVD virtual device for mobile but unable to create  for Android Wear.

Comment: Well, make sure that you installed the correct version of the SDK. Open the SDK manager and install the Platform and System Images for that SDK version. The Android SDK tools must be updated also. For more information, check these related questions [Fail to create Android virtual Device, “No system image installed for this Target”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541681) and [How can I add a system image for a target in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815950/how-can-i-add-a-system-image-for-a-target-in-android-studio).

Comment: Finally Solved!Access to the Google server was blocked.So I installed UltraSurf software and then inside studio ->From Tools->AVD ->Http Server->use proxy...It's working Now