# no cpu/abi system image available for this target

Tags: android, eclipse, android-developer-api

I'm getting this error when trying to create a virtual device (I'm brand new to android development, following a tutorial to get everything set up).

Everything I found simply said install the ARM or Intel System Image for the target that you're using.

I installed both of these for Android 4.4W (API20) and all 3 for Android L (API 20, L Preview) just in case.  I also tried having only 1 system image for each installed in case they somehow could interfere with each other, but that didn't work.

[image: SDK Manager]

[image: AVD]

If anyone has any ideas what else I'm missing, that would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Try launching both SDK manager and AVD manager as admin. Also Android Studio uses its own separate SDK by default. Check if the path in Android Studio points to the SDK you use.

Comment: Wow, silly me.  Thanks a lot, opening in administrator mode worked!

Comment: How do you resolve it? I have the same issue with latest Eclipse-ADT

Comment: Visit : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488419/unable-to-create-android-virtual-device

Have a detailed explanation of how things work.

Comment: Visit : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488419/unable-to-create-android-virtual-device

Have a detailed explanation of how things work.

Answer (score 1):

The SDK just got dumb, remove the images and reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by **James** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488419/unable-to-create-android-virtual-device):

> Simply because CPU/ABI says "No system images installed for this
>   target". You need to install a system images.
>
> In the Android SDK Manager check that you have installed "ARM EABI v7a
>   System Image" (for each Android version from 4.0 and on you have to
>   install a system image to be able to run a virtual device)