# Unable to create Android Virtual Device (AVD)

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am new to android development and I am having problem creating a new AVD. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 running on Intel® Core™ i5-4670 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 4, with 64 bit OS.

I have already looked at the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488419/unable-to-create-android-virtual-device), but it didnt help me.

I also successfully installed KVM as given in the [intel website](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture#_Toc358213272). But I didn't find any CPU/ABI system image while creating a new AVD as shown below :

[image: AVD Dialog]

**UPDATE :**
This is how my Android SDK manager looks like :

[image: Android SDK Manager]

I don't know what I am missing. Kindly help.

Comment: have u downloaded system images via sdk manager?

Comment: @HirakChhatbar I have updated the question with an image of the SDK Manager, it does not seem give any option to download the system images, or am I overlooking at something?

Comment: U can connect to internet, and refresh SDK manager!

Comment: Instead of using the eclipse provided with the ADT bundle you should download fresh eclipse (min Juno) from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and then install the android plugin in it. This will solve your AVD problem.

Comment: where are other apis? o_O . Try Tools ----> Options ----> Clear Cache and then Packages-----> Reload in ur sdk manager

Comment: @user2330675 I just did that but the result is same :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that I was unable to connect to internet from SDK manager as my system is configured to use a proxy. Unlike most softwares which automatically show a dialog that asks for username and password, the android SDK manager didn't automatically ask for any username and password.

In the Android SDK Manager, click on **tools** > **options**...

then enter the details in the following dialog and click on **close**
[image]

Thats it !!! 
Now I am able to update and download as anyone would do from the Android SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

in your second image you posted, you would get options under many api levels for System image, download any one of them as per your need and than try to make an avd

Comment: how do I get to see all those options? Currently I am able to see the options as shown above in my second image.

Comment: click on Package-> show updates and new packages. if you still don't see anything you are not able to load any of the android API, try getting a new SDK.

Comment: Your SDK manager did not load completely as this image shows, you should check add on sites in the tab