# SDK has been installed but in AVD manager no system image can be found

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I use macosx yosemite, all environment configured and works for another software development.
Try to learn some android development, after installed Intellij 14 and SDK, I found I cann't create AVD in AVD manager. Just like this, after choose hardware there is no system image found.
But, there are system images displayed for only one time (it's not the first time I run AVD MANAGER) I try to create AVD, but after that time I have never seen them again.

Comment: It displays below what are the errors when you are creating new devices. Check that out.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488419/unable-to-create-android-virtual-device) Is your problem same ?