# Can't create an AVD - no CPU/ABI system image available

Tags: android, meteor, android-virtual-device

I am trying to create a Android emulator with 5.1.1 for a Meteor App. I have been following the steps so far, but when I try to create the `AVD`, I get the message **"No CPU/ABI system image available for this target"**.

I have read that I need to go to the Android SDK and install "ARM EABI v7a System Image", but as you can see in the screenshot, that option does not seem to be available.

Did I screw something up?

[image]

**UPDATE**

I am not sure if it is important, but when I open the SDK, I get these messages:

> Fetching https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
>
> Fetched Add-ons List successfully
>
> Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
>
> Done loading packages.
>
> Fetching https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
>
> Failed to fetch URL ttps://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: peer not authenticated
>
> Fetched Add-ons List successfully
>
> Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
>
> Failed to fetch URL https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml, reason: SSLPeerUnverified peer not authenticated
>
> Done loading packages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to create Android Virtual Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488419/unable-to-create-android-virtual-device)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I al ready read it, and while the solution posted there says that I have on install ARM EABI with the SDK manager, I explicitely show that I have no such option in my SDK Manager. I dont know if it may be because Android 5.1.1 or why...

Comment: You must have at least any one system images for create AVD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow below steps :

1. Open SDK
2. Go to Tools menu
3. Select Option
4. check following checkbox which is shown in below image.
   [image]
5. Restart SDK and you will see all things.